# HtmlUnitDrivers scrolling down the page is not working in java even after enabling the javascript

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

Does anybody out there know how to scroll the page using HTML Unit drivers?
Please let me know whats the best way to scroll the page down until the last element is loaded using HTML unit drivers?

I have tried all these possibilities in HTML unit drivers, but looks like nothing actually loads the page as it scrolls down. Basically, the page is not scrolling down at all...

After successfully logging in, I'm trying to scroll down the page until the last element and get the page source.

code:

```
      htmlUnitdriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    //htmlUnitdriver.executeScript("scroll(0,300);");

    //htmlUnitdriver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

    //htmlUnitdriver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,3000)", "");

    //((JavascriptExecutor) htmlUnitdriver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,20000)", "");
```

Hoping somebody can help me...

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to know if Selenium HtmlUnitDriver provides any facility to scroll down the page even though the actual page does not render in a browser.
I can fetch new records on page only if can scroll the page.
Please share if you could find a solution for this.

Comment: Hi Hanuman, I got scrolling down the page working in HtmlUnitDriver in selenium Java see Below for the my working code.                 driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,3000)", new Object[] { "" });

Comment: Thanks sandprogrammer,  I'll try this. Hope this will work in my case as well.

Comment: @sandprogrammer, I have done similar thing, what you mentioned driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,3000)", new Object[] { "" });  But, still its not working in my case. Its not scrolling at all. And Even after scrolling I am getting same result, what I was getting earlier. Also, I checked this with driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();

Answer (score 1):

I too tried to scroll webpage using HtmlUnitDriver with below code:

```
jse = (JavascriptExecutor)wd;
        //((JavascriptExecutor)wd).executeScript("window.scroll(0, 250));");
        log.info("Scrolling... ");
        //jse.executeScript("window.scroll(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
        //jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
        //jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight));");
        //jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,3000)", "");
         wd.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,3000)", new Object[] { "" });
```

But no success with any of the above code snippet (by uncommenting each).
For my requirements scrolling is so important. 
 Just got some info that unlike PhantomJS, HtmlUnitDriver doesn't have enough support for JavaScript.